# Meaning of もてり and use of が

Tags: grammar, particles, classical-japanese, potential-form

> 白き布 もて盤上を 磨きたり 人は心に 鏡をもてり。

Is もてり 持てる？ If so, in that case why does a potential verb have the が particle?

Answer (score 6):

This is not the potential form of 持つ, but the 已然形 of 持つ plus the 終止形 of the 助動詞 り. In this case, the combination corresponds to modern Japanese 持っている.

Comment: Addendum: In other words it's a Classical Japanese grammar. See the dictionary entry of [り](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%8A).

Comment: Sorry; I assumed the fact that this was CJ was understood from the OP's use of the "Old Japanese" tag.

Comment: I see. Probably you're right. I was kind of confused because OP is asking about potential verb which doesn't exist in the Classical grammar.

Comment: Is that classical Japanese form really 磨**き**たり?  Or did OP make a typo of 磨**い**たり?

Comment: @istrasci It's indeed 磨きたり. But talking of that, the reduced form of 連用形 seems to have appeared in colloquialism as early as the 9th century.